# sending data from directive to component in angular4

Tags: angular, scope, components, directive

I have a directive being used in the component.
The directive returns processed data back to the component through a callback.

The issue is when the method in the component is invoked **'this'** start referring to the directive instead of the component.

My component is ImageFileReadDirective its used like this in abc component.

```
<input #imageInput type="file"
     accept="image/*,.MOV,.MPEG4,.MP4,.AVI,.WMV,.MPEGPS,.FLV,.3GPP,.WebM"
     appImageFileRead
     [onImageDropCtrlFn]="imageDropped"
     [resize_max_height]="300"
     [resize_max_width]="300"
     [resize_quality]="0.9"
     [resize_type]="image/png"
     [when_to_compress]="3"
     id="imageInput"
     class="button"/>
```

imageDropped method is in the component in which this directive is used.

```
 imageDropped(fileDetails: any) {
            **//REFERS TO DIRECTIVE SCOPE**
            var self = this;
   **//THIS BECOMES UNDEFINED**  
   this.modalService.setImage(fileDetails.fileDetails.base64FileData);


        }
```

modal service in imported in the component.

Please guide .I want to bind this method to the scope of the component.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what i did.
added a output in the directive:

```
 @Output() private filesUploadedEmiter: EventEmitter<File[]> = new EventEmitter();
```

and in the directive call in the component:

```
<div  class="form-group text-area"
   id="file-drop"
   appImageFileRead
   [resize_max_height]="300"
   [resize_max_width]="300"
   [resize_quality]="0.9"
   [resize_type]="image/png"
   [when_to_compress]="3"
   (filesChangeEmiter)="imageDropped($event)">
```

In this way the scope remained with the component

Answer (score 0):

You can `bind` the context before passing to directive.

```
public ngOnInit(){
    this.imageDropCtrlFn = this.imageDropped.bind(this);
}
```

Now you make the `imageDropCtrlFn` as callback to directive like,

```
...
[onImageDropCtrlFn]="imageDropCtrlFn"
...
```

This would bind the component context with `imageDropCtrlFn`.